# modulus operation applied to both sides of an equals sign

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $$a+b=c$$
is it permissible to write:
$$(a+b)\mod m =(c)\mod m$$ where $\mod m$ is the usual modulus operation in the modulo $m$ world. Is there a proof for this property if this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its permissible, but by *definition* -- so there's no proof (nor any need to prove it).  By definition, the $=$ sign means that the two sides represent the same thing, so anything done to both sides equally does not change anything about the representations, so they remain equal.

We do need to be a little more precise about "thing" above -- thanks to Bill Dubuque for pointing this out patiently in the comments.

What we do to both sides of the equals sign should be *apply a single-valued function*.  In this case we (assuming $a,b$ and $c$ are integers) apply the modulo function.  We could square the sides, and still preserve the equals sign (for complex $a,b$ and $c$ now); but we cannot apply (say) the square-root operation without being clear that we are treating it as a single-valued function (many "proofs" that $1=0$ rely on taking a square-root and claiming that $-\sqrt{a} = +\sqrt{b}$, with some obnubilation).

Comment: Not any "thing" but rather, any (single-valued) *function*

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks!  Answer corrected :)

Comment: My comment means: if $f$ is a (single-valued) function on $\Bbb Z$ then $\,j = k\,\Rightarrow\, f(j) = f(k).\, $ OP is the special case $\, f(n) = n\bmod m\ $. What you wrote does not reflect that.